# Guava RateLimiter doesn't apply throttling after a delay

Tags: java, guava, throttling

I have been playing around with Guava RateLimiter and found that it doesn't apply throttling just after a delay (if the rateLimiter is left unused for period of time).

Below is the sample code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(1);
        
        System.out.println("#1 Before delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("#2 Before delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("#3 Before delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        
        System.out.println("#1 After delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("#2 After delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("#3 After delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        
        System.out.println("-----------------------------");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        
        System.out.println("#1 After delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("#2 After delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        System.out.println("#3 After delay waitTime= "+  rateLimiter.acquire());
        
    }
```

And here is the result:

#1 Before delay waitTime= 0.0

#2 Before delay waitTime= 0.993215

#3 Before delay waitTime= 0.998329

---

**#1 After delay waitTime= 0.0**

**#2 After delay waitTime= 0.0**

#3 After delay waitTime= 0.999903

---

**#1 After delay waitTime= 0.0**

**#2 After delay waitTime= 0.0**

#3 After delay waitTime= 0.999921

Wondering as to why the first two attempts after a delay (Highlighted in bold above) are processed with no throttling (waitTime=0.0)

Comment: I don't see anything explicitly explaining that behaviour in the docs, but it does mention that it aims to allow *on average* `rate` requests per second and that burst are allowed if the rate limiter was idle, so this might be what causes this effect.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I agree. There are no explicit statements in the documentation. 
Although they have mentioned below, it is confusing:
" When the rate limiter is unused, bursts of up to
   * {@code permitsPerSecond} permits will be allowed, with subsequent requests being smoothly limited at the stable rate of {@code permitsPerSecond}. "

Comment: Indeed, that statement would lead me to believe that only the first call should have 0 delay, but keep in mind that this is meant to maintain an average rate over time, so slight deviation from that exact behaviour could still maintain that requirement. If you need something more stringent, then maybe this class is not exactly what you need.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Thanks for the advice. I probably have to explore other options if that is  case. Thanks again.